# Weblogic to JBoss EAP 6.4 Migration - Servlet loading threw java.lang.RuntimeException: NOT IMPLEMENTED

Tags: jboss, migration

I am currently working in a Weblogic to JBoss migration project. The source codes build easily, but when try to deploy ear file, getting error message as follows:

```
23:20:35,706 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[xyz]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) JBWEB000289: Servlet xyz-rest-api threw load() exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: NOT IMPLEMENTED
 at org.jboss.util.file.ArchiveBrowser.getBrowser(Unknown Source) [jboss-archive-browsing-5.0.0alpha-200607201-119.jar:5.0.0.Alpha (build: CVSTag=HEAD date=200607201119)]
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:610) [hibernate-entitymanager-3.2.1.ga.jar:]
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:341) [hibernate-entitymanager-3.2.1.ga.jar:]
 at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:126) [hibernate-entitymanager-3.2.1.ga.jar:]
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:290) [spring-orm-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310) [spring-orm-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117) [spring-context-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:922) [spring-context-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) [spring-context-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651) [spring-webmvc-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:602) [spring-webmvc-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665) [spring-webmvc-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:521) [spring-webmvc-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:462) [spring-webmvc-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [spring-webmvc-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
 at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1100) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3593) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3802) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
 at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
 at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
 at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
 at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
23:20:36,167 DEBUG [org.apache.jasper.compiler] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) JBWEB005025: Parent class loader is: ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.XYZ-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT-JBOSS.ear.XYZ-war-1.0-
```

Comment: FYI - check the [JBoss Windup migration tool](https://github.com/windup/windup/wiki).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're using an old Hibernate 3 in your application, which is not compatible with EAP 6.x. Use the Hibernate which is bundled within the EAP.

More, even if it was, your Hibernate library uses some alpha version of a library that I don't know: `jboss-archive-browsing-5.0.0alpha-200607201-119.jar`
Using alpha libraries in production is not a good idea in general.

```
Servlet xyz-rest-api threw load() exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: NOT IMPLEMENTED
at org.jboss.util.file.ArchiveBrowser.getBrowser(Unknown Source) [jboss-archive-browsing-5.0.0alpha-200607201-119.jar:5.0.0.Alpha (build: CVSTag=HEAD date=200607201119)]
...
```

Lastly, have a look at the [JBoss Windup migration tool](https://github.com/windup/windup/wiki) which might help you with these kind of issues. It primarily targets exactly your use case - WebLogic to JBoss EAP.latest migration